# Can we install 2 access points on the same network with different SSID?

Tags: wireless-access-point

I have a network over 2 floors. i had 1 access point on the top floor and need to put another on the bottom floor but with different SSID & password. can it be possible.. Please Help.. 
Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if they are going to the same network, kind of pointless in the long run, but, yes you can!

Try using different channels to stop interference and overlapping.

FYI, if they are going to the same network, you may want to see if your wireless access point can do multiple SSIDs, then, you can offer both to all floors.

Answer (score 0):

With Cisco gear, you can run multiple SSIDs (with different passwords) off of the same set of access points.  AP coverage does not simply cover a floor.  It can also bleed over into the floor above and/or below the floor the AP is located on.  You can try to lower the AP power level to prevent this from happening, but this will also effect coverage on the floor where you actually want coverage.